# problems with javascript c, e, t, q, w, A, u, B, m, h, d, C, r, x, D, y

Tags: javascript

hello I am learning to work with javascript and I would like to know what values these letters have in javascript or what I would like to understand.

I'll leave variables around here

```
 var b = document,
    c, e, t, q, w, A, u, B, m, h, d, C, r, x, D, y = document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1];
E = b.getElementsByName("fb_dtsg")[0].value, n = 0, p = 0;
k = {};




var b;
    p = !p;
    this.innerHTML = (p ? "(DES)" : "") + "SELECIONAR TODOS ";
    b = document.getElementsByName("friend");
    for (var a in b) a = +a, b[a] && (b[a].checked = p, b[a].parentElement.style.backgroundColor = p ? "#D13B1D" : "#3B5998", p ? k[b[a].parentElement.id] = !0 : delete k[b[a].parentElement.id])
});
```

Comment: hi! The snippet you provided doesnt do much. If you are interesting starting to learn to code this is great! Have a look at Mozilla Javascript tutorial; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Variable names don't have any special meaning, the programmer can use almost any name they want for their variables. Ordinarily they try to use words that describe what the variable is being used for, and this makes it easier to understand what the program is doing.

The code you've shown appears to be the result of processing some Javascript with a *minifier*. This is an application that converts a program to a shorter version that does the same thing, to reduce the time it takes to download the program. One of the things it does is replace most of the variable names with shorter names, so it ends up with lots of 1- and 2-letter variables that are no longer helpful in understanding the code.

If you want to understand what the code is doing, you should try to find the original code. Even expert programmers have trouble deciphering minified code.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your explanation, you do not know how to remove this modification to be able to see the original code?